# AttributeError: 'MyWindow' object has no attribute 'on_name_combo_changed'

Tags: python, combobox, gtk3

```
class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Grid example")
        grid = Gtk.Grid()

        #combobox
        devices_list = Gtk.ListStore(int, str)
        devices_list.append([1, "Device 1"])
        devices_list.append([2, "Device 2"])
        name_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(devices_list)
        *name_combo.connect("changed", self.on_name_combo_changed)*
        name_combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
        grid.attach(name_combo, 5, 0, 2, 1)
```

Hey guys I am new to python but I am so stuck with this error. I have followed tutorials as well as docs but I cant seem to figure this one out. I cant figure out why it says it has no attribute even though when I am mentioning it after 'self.'

Comment: `on_name_combo_changed` has to be your own method in class. I don't see `def on_name_combo_changed(self)` it in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your method `on_name_combo_changed(self, widget)` in your class.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Grid example")

        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(grid)

        #combobox
        devices_list = Gtk.ListStore(int, str)
        devices_list.append([1, "Device 1"])
        devices_list.append([2, "Device 2"])

        name_combo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(devices_list)
        name_combo.connect("changed", self.on_name_combo_changed)
        name_combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
        grid.attach(name_combo, 5, 0, 2, 1)

        self.show_all()

    def on_name_combo_changed(self, widget):
        print('ComboBox:', widget)


app = MyWindow()
Gtk.main()
```

Python GTK+ 3 Tutorial: [13. ComboBox](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/combobox.html)